# Trace multiple functions using redbug from command line

Tags: erlang

When tracing function calls using [redbug](https://code.google.com/p/eper/wiki/redbug) from an Erlang shell, I can trace multiple functions at the same time by passing a list of strings to `redbug:start`:

```
redbug:start(["foo:bar -> return", "bar:baz -> return"], []).
```

Using redbug from the command line, I can trace a single function without problems:

```
redbug -setcookie s3cret mynode@localhost "foo:bar->return"
```

But I can't seem to find a way to trace multiple functions from the command line.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
./priv/bin/redbug -setcookie s3cret mynode@localhost '"foo:bar->return","foo:baz->return"'
```

or

```
 ./priv/bin/redbug -setcookie s3cret mynode@localhost '["foo:bar->return","foo:baz->return"]'
```

You can pass comma separated list of strings, but *you can't use spaces*. Redbug internally surrounds input with "[" and "]" and then tries to parse that expression with `erl_scan` and `erl_parse`. If it fails, then it passes unparsed string (that is why syntax for one function is easy). If it succeeds, it calls:

```
redbug:start(["foo:bar->return", "foo:baz->return"], []).
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks!